Indentation and text wrapping in lists
I intend to create lists where the list index is indented, but the text is flush with left and right margins, and further text wraps around the list index. Currently, this is what happens using enumitem package in the below MWE.
\documentclass{article}                                                                                                                                                  

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
                                                                               
\begin{document}
This is a minimal working example with text wrapping in a paragraph as the
linewidth/textwidth is breached.
\begin{enumerate}[label={(\arabic*)}]
  \item \lipsum[1]
  \item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}


I want to generate lists where the text wrapping, similar to that of paragraphs, is achieved in lists as well. I have looked at a similar post which does what I need but without the label/index indentation and label customization. What would I need to do further to achieve these functionalities?

What exactly do you mean by I want to generate lists where the text wrapping similar to that of paragraphs is achieved in lists as well.? Looks like you are looking for the wide option for enumitem

I would like to have the second line of the indexed item to start at the left margin. For example, in the above MWE, I want vestibulum to start flush with left margin rather than under Lorem.

That is what wide does

Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you @daleif.

@daleif do you want to write up an answer?

If you don't want to have the item text aligned to the right of the number, but instead let the text use the will (text)width, look into the wide option for `enumitem.
\documentclass{article}                                                         \usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
                                                                               
\begin{document}
This is a minimal working example with text wrapping in a paragraph as the
linewidth/textwidth is breached.
\begin{enumerate}[label={(\arabic*)},wide,noitemsep]
  \item \lipsum[1]
  \item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}


